# Tableau: Sliding filter for date, but with a fixed range

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to create a sliding filter for date in Tableau, but I want the range to be fixed to one day.

For example, the whole filter scale will be from Jan 1, 2020 to December 31, 2020.

I want the viewer to be able to slide along the scale to select a specific date (e.g. June 6, 2020 - June 6, 2020), but not be able to change the size of the range to something longer than one day.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need only filters for any tech reason or would you be open to consider parameters? additionally: will your range always be 1-day wide?

Comment: My range would always be 1-day wide, and I'd be open to considering parameters. As long as it's something the user can interact with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking to filters, do you have already turned your filter data into a discrete filter (blue pill)?

If so, then you should be able to edit your filter and presenting it like a single value / slider.

[image]

If you're open to use parameter, you can right-click your date column and select Create-Parameter.

Doing so you should be getting a parameter already filled with all the dates in your column which you can then modify (if you want to get rid of some dates).

Once you show your parameter, it will appear in your worksheet/dashboard and you can edit especially in terms of how it looks like.

In your scenario, you probably want to set it as a slider:

[image]

Since the parameter alone won't filter your data, you also need to create a Calculated field with a condition.

Comment: Thanks so much! I went ahead with the filter option :)

Comment: nice: keep in mind parameters when you'll face some advanced scenario in terms of order of calculus ;-)